# git: Select branch when fetching specific file

Tags: git, git-archive

It is possible to define a specific branch when fetching a file as follows:

```
git archive --remote=git@my.git.server:namespace/projectname.git HEAD:path/to/file somefile.sql | tar -x
```

This will retrive the file from the default project branch.

How is it possible to select a **specific branch** for the above file retrieval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, turns out this is the way to go about it, when say someone want to get the above file from `develop` branch:

```
git archive --remote=git@my.git.server:namespace/projectname.git develop:path/to/file somefile.sql | tar -x
```